# How to handle Ajax json response within a phonegap app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know there are a couple posts on here with this topic however i cant seem to piece together the parts i need to make this work.

I am converting a web application into an app using phonegap and i am trying create a search form that returns json data. I am having trouble understanding how to handle this ajax request or at least how to write it. The php script is working fine and returning data with the json_encode() function. Essentially i need a user to search an address (using google maps autocomplete for places; working fine) and that address will be the data sent to that url. Now where i get stuck is how to display this response?

**Js:**

```
$('#searchButton').click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data:$('#autocomplete').val(),
                url: 'http://mylandlordscore.com/ws/ws_search.php?search=',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    if(response.length != 0) {
                        response.each().innerHtml('<div>' + response + '</div>');
                        };
                    }
            });

  });
```

**Html:**

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="autocomplete" class="form-control" name="search" autocomplete="off" />
    <input id="searchButton" type="button" value="submit" />
</form>
<ul id="thelist">
    <li>data</li>
    <li>data</li>
    <li>data</li>
</ul>
```

I started building a jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1ww36cyk/2/) if anyone could help me out!

Comment: not going to work on jsfiddle because php script is another  domain, if you have the same approach in your app then it could be a probelm too due to "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" limitation of ajax.

Answer (score 0):

`response.each().innerHtml('div' + response + '</div>');` this is probably the issue. there is no `innerHTML` property or method of `.each()`.

Try replacing with something like:

```
response.each(function(item) {
    $('#thelist').append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
});
```